# Validate two dates of this "dd-MMM-yyyy" format in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have two dates `18-Aug-2010` and `19-Aug-2010` of this format. How to find whether which date is greater?

Comment: Your question is a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript The solution described there should help you.

Comment: is the language for the text guaranteed to be english?

Comment: @David can't get what you are trying to say?

Comment: 18-Aug is English specific...10-Oct is English, but in Indonesian (for example) it would be 10-Okt etc...the MMM desc is language dependent...unless you are guaranteeing a specific language

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create a custom parsing function to handle the format you want, and get date objects to compare, for example:

```
function customParse(str) {
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
      n = months.length, re = /(\d{2})-([a-z]{3})-(\d{4})/i, matches;

  while(n--) { months[months[n]]=n; } // map month names to their index :)

  matches = str.match(re); // extract date parts from string

  return new Date(matches[3], months[matches[2]], matches[1]);
}

customParse("18-Aug-2010");
// "Wed Aug 18 2010 00:00:00"

customParse("19-Aug-2010") > customParse("18-Aug-2010");
// true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the parsing manually, for your given format, but I'd suggest you use the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library to parse the dates to Date objects and then compare.
Check it out, its awesome!

And moreover, its a great addition to your js utility toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

The native `Date` can parse "MMM+ dd yyyy", which gives:

```
function parseDMY(s){
  return new Date(s.replace(/^(\d+)\W+(\w+)\W+/, '$2 $1 '));
}
+parseDMY('19-August-2010') == +new Date(2010, 7, 19) // true
parseDMY('18-Aug-2010') < parseDMY('19-Aug-2010')     // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the 'dd-MMM-yyyy' format isn't an accepted input format of the `Date` constructor (it returns an "invalid date" object) so we need to parse this ourselves. Let's write a function to return a `Date` object from a string in this format.

```
function parseMyDate(s) {
    var m = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
    var match = s.match(/(\d+)-([^.]+)-(\d+)/);
    var date = match[1];
    var monthText = match[2];
    var year = match[3];
    var month = m.indexOf(monthText.toLowerCase());
    return new Date(year, month, date);
}
```

`Date` objects implicitly typecast to a number (milliseconds since 1970; epoch time) so you can compare using normal comparison operators:

```
if (parseMyDate(date1) > parseMyDate(date2)) ...
```

Comment: Instead of using hackish `* 1` hacks to cast the result to an integer, you should rather use `parseInt(s.match(/(\d+)/g)[1], 10)` to get the Integer object.

Comment: With the OP's format `s.match(/(\d+)/g);` will return you a two element array, e.g. `"12-Aug-2010".match(/(\d+)/g); // ["12", "2010"]`, you are accessing the `1` and `2` indexes. Also you need some way to map the three letter month name with the month number...

Comment: @Denis in this case we don't even need to convert the strings to numbers, the [`Date` constructor](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.3) will convert each argument internally `ToNumber` ;)

Comment: @CMS, I've fixed both problems. Fixed the first one by removing 'global search' tag. Fixed the second one by using `indexOf` to search.

Comment: @Delan, nice, you just have to adjust your indexes again for the `date` and `year` matches (and you can remove those ugly `* 1` without problems) :)

Comment: No, they are correct now when the `g` modifier is off because `0` is the entire matched string, while `1` and on are the captured matches. I'll remove the multiplication :D

Comment: @Delan, I see, but then, the two `match` method calls (for the `date` and `year` variables) will give you exactly the same result. You will be able to capture only the `date` part, not the year.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. I've fixed it to run one match call that captures all three 'fields' of the date. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update: IE10, FX30 (and likely more) will understand "18 Aug 2010" without the dashes - Chrome handles either

so `Date.parse("18-Aug-2010".replace("/-/g," "))` works in these browsers (and more)

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3Tj8k/)

Hence

```
function compareDates(str1,str2) {
  var d1 = Date.parse(str1.replace("/-/g," ")),
      d2 = Date.parse(str2.replace("/-/g," "));
  return d1<d2;
}
```