# jQuery validation plugin: validate custom date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, validation

I am using jQuery Validate plugin to validate my form, how can i validate a custom date with this date format DD-MMM-YYY (23-Mar-2012).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom date format with jQuery validation plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Create a custom validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("mydate", function(value, element) { 
  return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?-\w\w\w-\d\d\d\d/.test(value); 
}, "Please specify the date in DD-MMM-YYYY format");
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/03/31/client-side-date-validation-using-jquery-plugins/

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customDateValidator", function(value, element) {
        // parseDate throws exception if the value is invalid
        try{jQuery.datepicker.parseDate( 'm/dd/yy', value);return true;}
        catch(e){return false;}
    },
    "Please enter a valid date"
);
```

Check also referenced post: [Custom date format with jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

Also: [Validate two dates of this "dd-MMM-yyyy" format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509683/validate-two-dates-of-this-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-javascript)