# jquery validation for date is not accepted jan date

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem of date validation. I used following reg expression for enter date in `dd-mmm-yyyy` format only

```
dateValidatorRegex = /^(\d{1,2})(-)(?:(\(jan)|(feb)|(mar)|(apr)|(may)|(jun)|(jul)|(aug)|(sep)|(oct)|(nov)|(dec))(-)(\d{4})$/i;
```

But in this case when I entered date in month of `jan` It doesn't passes the validation. Please suggest on it.

Comment: Why the backslash before the opening parenthesis right before `jan`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate two dates of this "dd-MMM-yyyy" format in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509683/validate-two-dates-of-this-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression is wrong at backslash. It will be,

```
var dateValidatorRegex = /^(\d{1,2})(-)(?:((jan)|(feb)|(mar)|(apr)|(may)|(jun)|(jul)|(aug)|(sep)|(oct)|(nov)|(dec)))(-)(\d{4})$/i;
```

By that backslash jan month is not validate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to lengthy regexs which do not handle leap years

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cNtb4/)

```
function isValidDate(str) {
  var d = new Date(Date.parse(str.replace(/-/g," "))), parts = str.split("-");
  var monthNum = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul",
                  "aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"].indexOf(parts[1].toLowerCase());
  return parts[0]==d.getDate() && 
         monthNum == d.getMonth() && 
         parts[2]==d.getFullYear();
}
```

Note that the .indexOf for arrays is not compatible with older IEs so you can do

```
  var monthNum = {"jan":0,"feb":1,"mar":2,"apr":3,"may":4,
                  "jun":5,"jul":6,"aug":7,"sep":8,"oct":9,
                  "nov":10,"dec":11].[parts[1].toLowerCase()];
```

instead

Comment: Liked your Live Demo button. Keen to know where did you get hold of that. Would love to use next time :) <kbd></kbd>

Comment: I got it from here a long time ago. Some purist edit my posts to remove it. Not sure why.